# jquery treeview highlighting selected item

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, treeview

I am using a jQuery treeview, to display an organization tree hierarchy, I display the selected organization's details on the same form by using AJAX.

So the question is, how do I make the current (selected) item highlighted, does treeview support that (I tried selected, persistence etx, no luck, but I am new to jquery anyways.), or should I solve this on my own.

thanks in advance

Comment: It will help if you can point out which treeview plugin you are using.

Comment: It is the jquery plug-in treeview.

Answer (score 0):

try applying highlighting class to the selected item:

```
$("CLICKED ELEMENT'S ID").addClass("HIGHLIGHT CLASS");
```

if you are using asp.net treeview then you will need to update `td` containing link like this:

```
$("CLICKED ELEMENT'S ID").parent().addClass("HIGHLIGHT CLASS");
```

Comment: so jquery treeview cannot handle this?
the solution you recommend also requires me to keep a track of highlighted item, so I can unselect it first then highlight the selected one. I was hoping treeview was able to display the selected node distinguisable than others.

Comment: I think treeview has no support for that yet !